# SpecFlow has parsing problems

Tags: c#, regex, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I have a problem with parsing steps in .feature file with implementation which is defined in steps.cs file. Beside that, the same step was parsed successfully just a few lines upper in same scenario in .feature file. All steps bind successfully, with exception of last 2 steps, which fail to bind, although these steps appear for 2nd time.

I tried to delete .cache files in %TEMP%, but it is not that. Besides that, step definition is like:

From steps.cs file, when I do *Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S*, I get 2 steps recognized, which is ok.

We use VS 2015, specflow for VS2015, and SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator as generator. Same happens with VS 2019, with specflow for VS2019 and SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator as generator. 
I must say that we have a plenty of scenarios and features which behave nice (with very very basic regex).

Anybody got any clue for this?

Also, when I enable tracing (Tools->Options->SpecFlow) in Output window of VS, I get the messaages:

```
[08:51:21.6011171] EditorParser: Start full parsing
[08:51:21.6041087] EditorParser: Finished full parsing in 2 ms, 6 errors
```

**Edit**: when I open .feature file for first time on opening solution, it parses everything well at first glance. But after 30 seconds, some of steps transit to unrecognized state, as mentioned above.

**Edit 1**: seems like this part of regex makes problems - `\s*(for remote point ""(.*)"")?`.
When I put space before open brace (, I get good parsing. But my steps then aren't functioning anymore.

Edit 2: images removed.

Edit 3: I've got mail from Andreas about this topic:

When the regex of a binding is getting to complex the Visual Studio Extension has problems to match them correctly. I fear your regex is already to complex for it.
The runtime should handle it just fine.
From my experience having these kind of checks in the regex make it hard to see then the error at runtime.
I think you only get an exception that the step can't be matched.
If I have such a restricted range of possible values as in your binding, I always have a runtime check that throws an exception if it doesn't pass.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the generated c# file and recompiling ?

Comment: Yes, i deleted .feature.cs file and did save to .feature file. I get new .feature.cs file but problem is still present. In generated file, next line appears 2 times (i will paste it only once): testRunner.Then("Assert Succeeded execution", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");

Comment: What do you mean by the last two steps fail to bind? Are you getting an error? Can you right-click on those steps and "go to definition"?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .vs folder in the root directory of your solution?

Comment: @greg it’s like i showed on screenshot for .feature file. Do you see how **Then** and **And** in last two steps are not recognized as keywords? I simply cannot navigate to step definition from those steps. If i do right click on them, ‘go to definition’ is disabled-grayed. I haven’t tried deleting .vs folder, but i will give it a try when i reach my office. I will say again, we have a plenty of well parsed scenarios, but this example is taken from solution of different team, and i copy it in our solution to check if it about some bad settings. But it has same bad behavior all the time.

Comment: Deleting .vs folder doesn't change anything.

Comment: I wonder if the feature file needs to have line endings fixed? Maybe the file has mixed Unix and Windows line endings, and that's throwing off the parser?

Comment: The output window for SpecFlow shows 6 errors. Those errors might show up in the "Errors" panel, or try looking through the SpecFlow output for the errors.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. There is something... I found some suspicious step definitions, which after are commented out, .feature file becomes well parsed (with defined and (purple) undefined steps).
**Edit**: updated step definition with problematic regex code